# PHPUnit Never uses the correct include_path

Tags: phpunit

I've recently installed PHPUnit on a Mac (10.8.3) (running PHP 5.4.7). When I attempt to a run a test `phpunit testfile.php` for example, I receive:

```
Warning: require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
directory in /Users/myusername/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' 
(include_path='.:') in /Users/myusername/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
```

The file, `/Users/myusername/pear/share/pear/File/Iterator/Autoload.php` exists.

`php.ini` correctly lists the pear directories in the include path:

`.:/php/includes:/usr/local/apache/lib/php:/Users/myusername/pear/share/pear/`

Yet when I `var_dump(get_include_path());` inside of the `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` file, it prints `.:` as if it's empty.

Dumping the value of `php_ini_loaded_file` instead, simply returns `false`.

Using `php -i |grep php\.ini` and `php --ini` only show one php.ini being used/loaded:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/apache/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/apache/lib/php.ini
```

I repeated the var_dumps of the include_path and the loaded_ini_file from a simple test.php file I ran from the command line and they print out the **correct** info. So something involved with phpunit is not loading the right/any php.ini.

I'm not using any configurations that are different than default - phpunit was just installed on this machine today.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the php.ini file you are using is the one loaded for cli php.  At least on my install of PHP on Linux, I have two php.ini files, one at /etc/php/cgi-php5.4/php.ini, and the other at /etc/php/cli-php5.4/php.ini.  If you change the cgi version, it won't by default affect the cli version, and would cause the include path to be empty.

---

Another place to check is the phpunit.xml file.  It has a section to specify the include path.  [See here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.configuration.html) for options available.  I'm not sure why phpunit would reset the path but this might be a way to solve the issue.

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/apache/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/apache/lib/php.ini - That's the only one I have and is what shows when using `php -i |grep php\.ini` - and `php --ini` shows no additional/other ini files

Comment: I repeated the var_dumps of the include_path and the loaded_ini_file from a simple test.php file I ran from the command line and they print out the correct info. So something involved with phpunit is not loading the right/any php.ini.

Comment: Interesting.  I found some configuration options that might help, check the answer for details.

Comment: I've tried using the xml config file already, and I've also tried passing the path through `--include_path` but neither have any result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

After running

```
`pear config-get php_bin` -i | grep -E Configuration\ File\|include_path
```

It showed that Pear was using a different ini path than php-cli was:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
include_path => .: => .:
```

Turns out, Pear had been configured by the original/default Mac OS copy of PHP, not by the custom version I had installed later on.

A quick fix that may not be best long-term was to symlink the ini file it was trying to find:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache/lib/php.ini /etc/php.ini`

Afterwards, `phpunit FakeTest` commands are work, and the tests run.

Eventually I need to re-install/re-configure Pear to work with the version of php I've loaded.